# How to convert a string date into milliseconds in C/Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk

I have a string `"2017-07-30_00:00:00"` I want to convert this string into milliseconds in C/Android NDK. But did not find any function to do so. Some example which is in C++ `boost::` and any other libs which don't work in Android NDK. So if there is any way to do this in C/C++ that can be run in Android NKD, it will be helpful.

Comment: Is [`strptime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html) available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[strptime()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html) is suported by bionic (i.e. available in NDK).